# Map representation for localization

Tags: java, dictionary, localization, robotics, data-representation

I would like to write in Java localization system for a robot. However I am stuck at the very beginning. I don't know how to represent the map. The map is not complicated and will never be bigger than few meters by few meters. It doesn't change when robot is moving.

The readings that I will have from sensors are angle (provided by compass) and pairs of integers (angle and distance).

Comment: What is in the map? Is it discrete or vector based? And why do you want to represent a map? Isn't what you have a list of readings instead of a map?

Comment: Are you talking about coordinates of the robot?

Comment: Robot is in the wooden box of the size 1.5m x 1.5m. There are few obstacles (cubes generally). The robot should know the map. The left top corner of the environment is point 0,0.

I have to write a function which will take as an input readings from the sensor and give back (as an output) x, y coordinates of the robot and its angle.

I assumed I need to program somehow a map, so the robot is able to calculate it's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Probabilistic Robotics](http://probabilistic-robotics.org/) by Thrun, Burgard and Fox covers a number of different techniques for modelling maps suitable for robotics applications. These include:

- [Occupancy Grids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupancy_grid_mapping). Occupancy grids are conceptually similar to an image - black pixels are obstacles, white pixels are passable.
- Feature Based Maps. Feature based maps estimate position of each obstacle in a list.

The suitability of each approach depends on how sparse / cluttered the environment is and what types of sensors are available for updating the map.